# Java, Google App Engine, and JSONArray/JSONObject

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on an assignment and I can't seem to get a response from my instructor or the TA. The goal of the assignment is to use the Google App Engine to deploy an app that takes the URL of an image, converts it into a byte stream, stores it in the DataStore, then calls it back to be viewed on another page.

I've been able to store the image, but retrieving it is another matter. We're supposed to use JSON arrays and objects to pass a string with the relevant data to a calling function, but Eclipse is telling me that GAE does not support JSON. Here's the error message:

> org.json.simple.JSONArray is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Furthermore, the Eclipse console is telling

> JSONArray cannot be resolved to a type

and

> JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type

What's really odd about this is that the instructor himself uses JSON in his demo app. I wish I could get a response from him regarding this issue, but he's being dodgy and has been somewhat absent all term.

Anyway, here's what I've got. Please let me know if there's something I'm doing wrong. **For the record, I'm not asking anyone to fix my code for me or give me working code - I'd just like a little help understanding my problem.**

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.jdo.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.*" %>

<%
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPMF().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        List<University> items = University.loadAll(pm);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        for (University item : items) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("uname", item.getNameOfUniversity());
            object.put("photoURL", item.getURLOfImage());
            array.add(object);
        }
        out.write(array.toString());
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
%>
```

Comment: did you added the **json.jar** in your build path of your eclipse project.

Comment: also try to use **org.json** library instead of **org.json.simple** as it is much more flexible and works 100% fine with GAE.

Comment: @AnkurJain Yes, the JSON library is in my build path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [add the missing jar file to your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285472/including-jar-files-in-eclipse-app-engine-project).

Also, for easier JSON creating parsing you should take a look at JSON mapper libraries: [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Comment: I have the jar in there, so it's not missing. The problem I think is that it's not compatible with GAE. What's really odd about that though is that everyone else in my class is using the same library and it works fine for them...